# C# Bitmap only loads when static file address is specified

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm trying to create a method which loads a image (png) and stores it in a Bitmap variable to be used later. The code is as follows:

```
 private static Bitmap LoadImage(string subfolderName, string imageName) {
            string fileSpec = string.Format(@".\Images\{0}\{1}.png", subfolderName, imageName);

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fileSpec);    


            return bitmap;
        }
```

As you can see its fairly simple, I store the file path in fileSpec and then use that as the parameter for creating the new bitmap. The issue is when I use this is that I get the following error:

```
"Parameter is not Valid"
```

The error points to this line:

```
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(fileSpec);
```

I have found that this is error is meant to happen when a file is non-existent, but the file is there and when I use a static file address such as this:

```
private static Bitmap LoadImage(string subfolderName, string imageName) {

            string st = @".\Images\Cards\CardBackRed.png"; //did this to test if it was working in any capacity at all

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(st);

            return bitmap;
        }
```

I get no error and image loads fine. Am I missing something really obvious? Help would really be appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you've shown, the error disappears when you hard-code the folder and file names. Therefore the `subfolderName` and `imageName` variables passed to your `LoadImage` method do not contain the values you expect.

You can demonstrate this by setting a breakpoint at the start of your `LoadImage` method, and checking the values of the `subfolderName` and `imageName` variables at that point.

Answer (score 0):

When combining multiple portions of a path, use the .NET-provided `Path.Combine()` method. It's *possible* that subfolderName already has a backslash in it, and you're doubling up on them. `Path.Combine()` checks for that for you, so it's safter to use. I suspect that's what's happening here.

```
string.Format(@".\Images\{0}\{1}.png", subfolderName, imageName);
```

Since you're using a relative path, I'm not exactly sure what you'll have to provide to make this work. Try what I've got below... it should start at the path of the currently executing assembly, which *should* be equivalent to `.`.

```
string fileSpec = 
    Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)),
                 "Images",
                 subfolderName,
                 imageName + ".png");
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately the same error occurs, any other suggestions?

Comment: The debugger shows the value of filespec as :  fileSpec "F:\\Users\\MYUSERNAME\\Documents\\Gui Games with shared game class\\Gui Games\\bin\\Debug\\Cards\\CardBackRed.png" string
"

Answer (score 0):

@Tetsuo_and_Youth, You set wrong file path
You say "The debugger shows the value of filespec as :   fileSpec   "F:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Documents\Gui Games with shared game class\Gui Games\bin\Debug\Cards\CardBackRed.png" string "  which is correct path.

which implies that the relative path should be

```
string fileSpec = string.Format(@".\{0}\{1}.png", subfolderName, imageName);
```

there is no "Images" folder under your "./bin/Debug/" folder

And also implies in your post, the second fileSpec is not set as you said for it is correct path.